# Modified files don't stay staged after stash save and stash pop

Tags: git, version-control

I have a bunch of **staged** files - some of them are `new file`, some of them are `modified`. I do `git stash save "message"` and all of them are stashed. That's ok. But when I do `git stash pop`, suddenly only the `new file` files are **staged** and the `modified` are not. Why is that?

Answer (score 6):

`git stash pop` mushes together the staged and unstaged (work-directory) changes, in just that way.

`git stash pop --index` keeps them separated, if it can (sometimes this is impossible due to existing staged stuff or merge states).

After `git stash pop` has mushed things together, it's fairly hard (not impossible but usually not worth the work) to get the dropped stash back so that you can try again with `--index`.  For this reason, I think people should get in the habit of using `git stash apply` (with or without `--index`) followed by `git stash drop` once they are happy with the result.  If you `apply`, the stash is still there, so you can `git reset --hard HEAD` to undo it and retry with `--index` when that was what you meant.  (This is especially useful when you mix up `--index` and `--keep-index`, which keeps happening to me. :-) )

Comment: Does the --index option applies the stashed changes to only the files which were staged??

Comment: No ... explaining in detail how `--index` "really works" is too complex for a comment, but it amounts to making use of the fact that `git stash save` creates (at least) *two* commits, one for the index/staging area, and one for the work dir.  Applying (or popping) with `--index` attempts to preserve the original staged/unstaged state, if it can.  (I'm not sure why the `stash` script does not do this as the default action, with a `--mush-together` option for the "too hard, can't do that" case.)